# All requests goes against the same action in Piranha

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, piranha-cms

I've started using Piranha CMS and really enjoining it, but now I came into a bit of trouble.

One of my pages is a contact form where I want to post an extended page model with contact information to the controller.

I've created a page template `Contact` and in the manager gui and I've set the setting `View` to `Contact`

The correct view is loaded but the problem is that all the requests goes against the `index` action method and not the `contact` action method in `PageController`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **view** is used to signal the controller what **view** should be used to render the page, **not** which action should be called. This can be used when several pages has the same type of data and logic, but should be rendered differently.

The field **route** is used to rewrite a page to a controller/action. The default route for a page is **Page** which means that requests to that page is rewritten to `~/page`, i.e the PageController and its Index action. If you wanted a certain type to be rewritten to the **contact** action of the PageController you set the route to **Page/Contact** which will rewrite the request to `~/page/contact`.

If you have a complex structure you should add custom controllers, for examples a ProductController. The route could then be set to **Product** rewriting the request to `~/product`.

I hope this clarifies things!

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Using this method, how would you parameters to the url?

Comment: Everything on the url trailing the matched permalink will be appended to the rewritten url, so there's no problem sending either query params or route params!